# Trackmine Error: Can't find Redmine IssueStatus: Accepted

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, pivotaltracker

This is driving me crazy.  I've tried to install the [trackmine plugin](https://github.com/capita/redmine_trackmine) to integrate pivotal tracker and redmine, but I continually have problems with dependancies and setup errors.

Now I have almost got it working, but when I add a story in Pivotal and modify it I get an email with this error:

```
Got error from Trackmine:
Error while reading activity message from Pivotal Tracker: Can't find Redmine IssueStatus: 'Accepted'
```

Any idea how I would fix that?

Comment: Nevermind... I've given up on this plugin and decided to use Redmine Backlogs instead.
It's already given me a really nice impression, looking forward to using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that starting a story creates a Redmine issue with status "Accepted". 
So you must have the status with that name otherwise you will get an error. You can add that status through administrator panel or manually from console. I use Trackmine everyday for more than year and it seems to work (Rails 2.3.5 + Redmine 1.0.4). 
Anyway good luck with Backlogs.